# Questions related to tense

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, past-perfect, present-tense, past-vs-past-perfect

I am kind of confused....
Are the two sentences below the same?

> 1. Let’s pretend that none of this had ever/never happened.
> 2. Let’s pretend that none of this have ever/never happened.

If it’s different, can you please be specific on how they are different from each other?

Comment: Neither sentence is very idiomatic. I would expect "Let's pretend that none of this [has] ever happened" (or "...that this never happened"). _None of this never happened_ is wrong - it's a double negative.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But if someone were to recall an event from the past (which does not affect the present moment), isn’t is possible to say “none of this had ever happened’ ? In other words, if an event is in the “distant past~past” range.

Comment: This ‘had happened’ is mentioned in the short story named “ Chef’s house” by Raymond Carver.

Comment: Edna from the Chef’s House says “Let’s suppose nothing had ever happened “

Comment: The ***Past** Perfect* version requires a past tense narrative context - for example, ***We decided** to pretend that none of this **had** ever happened.* The ***Present** Perfect* version works better with a present / future tense context: ***Let’s pretend** that none of this **has** [ever] happened.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence makes sense:

> Let’s pretend that none of this had ever happened.

The second sentence doesn't make grammatical sense:

> <strike>Let’s pretend that none of this have ever happened.</strike>

"*have ever happened*" isn't correct here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but you haven't explained *why* "have ever happened" isn't correct here.  I think it's because "none of this" requires a singular verb.  (If we said "none of these things" then a plural verb would work, and "none of these things have ever happened" would be grammatical.)  It may seem obvious, but the answers are for the benefit of learners, so it's better to spell things out.

Comment: @rjpond: "have ever happened" isn't correct here because ***none of this*** is a ***singular*** subject, so it would have to be *none of this **has** happened*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Agreed.  That's pretty much what I said (or meant) (*"None of this requires a singular verb*")

Comment: @rjpond: I beg your pardon - I was just about to putter off to deal with something else, and I didn't properly read your comment except the first and last line. I'll leave my comment there on the off-chance drumming the message home ***as well as*** spelling things out might help some future visitor, but I really should be more attentive! :)

Answer (score 1):

> Let’s pretend that none of this had ever/never happened.

> Let’s pretend that none of this have ever/never happened.

Both sentences are in present tense, and the noun phrase, 'none of this', is singular, hence 'has' could be more suitable than 'had' or 'have'.

For information, 'none of these' would be plural.

Also, in both examples, the adverb, 'never', if used would lead to double-negative.

Both examples hence are not recommended.

A guide on the use of 'none of' is shown below.

> None of

> We use none with of before the, demonstratives (this, that), possessives (my, your) or pronouns:

> None of his old friends knew what had happened to him.

> It doesn’t matter. None of it was your fault.

> We don’t use none of when there is already a negative word (not, n’t) in the clause:

> She doesn’t remember any of us.

> Not: She doesn’t remember none of us.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/no-none-and-none-of